# algolia filters and pagination error

Tags: algolia

can I actually use filters and pagination at the same query?
I can use filters and returns what I expected:

```
const query = { filters: `type: ${type}`};
```

but it returns error when I add page in query:

```
const query = { filters: `type: ${type}`, page: 2 };
```

err msg reads:

```
AlgoliaSearchError {name: "AlgoliaSearchError", message: "filters: Unexpected token string(Object]) expected end of filter at col 14", debugData: Array(1), statusCode: 400, __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask…}
```

Answer (score 5):

this should definitely works but it also depends on what does ${type} gets replaced with.

Can you try with:

`` const query = { filters: `type:"${type}"`, page: 2 }; ``

Notice the removal of spaces and addition of double quotes.
Could you log exactly your query object at the time of the error? That would help, thanks!

Comment: by adding double quotes and removing spaces, it works fine. thanks.